# Where are the Meteor server logs in Windows?

Tags: windows, logging, meteor

I am developing a Meteor application on Windows.  Are there log files being stored somewhere?  Where are they?

To be more specific, I am running the development server on my local pc.  I need to see any logs being created by the server.  I need to know where they are stored.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they are stored in files. You need to handle logging in your code and also look for meteor process STDOUT/STDERR.

Perhaps you can take a look at this project for a solution/inspiration:
https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-logger